# "no matching function call..." Where is this error coming from and how can I resolve it?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I've run into an issue with line 3 -  "no matching function for call to std::vector::push_back(int*)const" - can someone explain to me where this issue is coming from and how I can resolve it?

```
for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
   for(vector< vector<int> >::const_iterator it = x.begin(); it < x.end(); it++){
      it->push_back(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: When posting question about build errors, please include the *actual* error in the question body, using copy-paste to show the complete (and unedited) build log (including any informational notes and messages). Also if possible try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem and show that, or at the very least show declarations of all involved variables. You might also want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are iterating using a `const_iterator`. By definition, you cannot modify what a `const_iterator` references.  Use a non-const `iterator` instead:

```
for(vector< vector<int> >::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++){
      it->push_back(i);
```

Or, even better, you should use modern C++11 or later:

```
for (auto &x_vector: x)
     x_vector.push_back(i);
```

Don't you think that modern C++ is easier to write and understand?